# Javascript - Do references to methods prevent objects from being garbage collected?

Tags: javascript, methods, garbage-collection, es6-class

Suppose I have function that returns a method of an object that only exists in stack scope:

```js
class Item {
  constructor(name) { this.name = name }
  print() { console.log(`Item with name: ${this.name}`); }
}

function namePrinter(name) {
  return (new Foo(name)).bar
}

const printer = namePrinter('Alan')
printer() // prints 'Alan'
```

Does the reference to the `print()` method prevent the `Foo` instance from being garbage collected? My assumption is that underneath the ES6 OO sugar the `bar()` method gets bound to the `Foo` instance, causing it to store a reference to the object so that it can substitute it into `this`, but I'm not sure.

Side note - I realize I could make this work with something like the following, where the instance is part of the closure to an anonymous function, but that wouldn't work for my particular use case:

```
function newPrinter(name) {
  const item = new Item(name)
  return () => {
    item.print()
  }
}
```

Comment: "*My assumption is that underneath the ES6 OO sugar the bar() method gets bound to the Foo instance*" this assumption is incorrect. The shorthand method syntax does not do auto-binding. The only major difference to a regular function is that a method cannot be called with `new`. Other than that, it's the same as doing `Item.prototype.print = function() {}`

Comment: Thanks for the info! I suppose the method reference doesn't prevent the object from being garbage collected. Ah well.

Comment: Generally, garbage collectors are good at resolving unreachable cyclic references. If you have objects `a -> b` and `b -> a` each has a reference to each other. But if there are no other references to either `a` or `b` then GC would pick them up.